# Excel for Mac filtering not working...identical steps in Excel for Windows does

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function

I'm a new Mac user and am using Excel for Mac version 16.63.1 (22071301).  I've downloaded a ~700,000 record publicly available FAA dataset in csv format.  I'm trying to filter for the name Torgerson, which clearly exists in the dataset.

Unfiltered dataset showing Torgerson:

[image]

But when I try to use the filters, it shows as nothing found.

Failed attempt to filter on Torgerson:

[image]

I know Excel enough to know the entire range must be selected when doing the filtering, and have successfully filtered the same dataset using Excel on my PC.

Comment: I'm curious if you have ever really examined the cell contents closely, to ensure there's no possibility of non-printable characters, etc.  Imported text CSV files are prone to having some weird artifacts embedded that maybe the Mac and Windows versions have imported slightly differently?  This is weird to be replying to a problem about a spreadsheet that my name is actually in!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Max.  I think you're on to something.

Comment: Try to select the whole cells and then use the Filter.